# Is it possible to prevent saving images from my site?

Tags: html, image, internet-explorer

I have restricted  the right click option in my web page, but in IE it shows icons to Save Image, Print, Mail etc . I want to remove all of these. Is this possible?

Comment: Just as an FYI, if they can see the image, there is a copy of it on their computer, so you have already failed by that point. You can only prevent unmotivated users from saving in this case. All a motivated user would have to do is ask how to save the images on the appropriate stack exchange site.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It seems like everyone else who answered here didn’t read the question.

> I have restricted right clicking option in my web page , But IN IE it shows Icons to Save Image, print , mail etc . I want to remove all of these . IS it possible ??

**Yes, it is possible to remove these icons.** Just put the following in the `<head>` of your document.

```
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
```

As mentioned in the other answers, users will still be able to get the images if they really want to, no matter how hard you try to prevent it. If you don’t want the images to be copied, you shouldn’t use them on a website.

Comment: I think you hit the hammer on the nail! Shame on me for not reading the quetion carefully. :P

Comment: BTW:, it seems that this feature was only present in IE6.

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're talking about the [Image Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/using/howto/customizing/phototoolbar.mspx) in Internet Explorer. You can disable it with this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
</head>

</html>
```

Or, directly applied to an image:

```
<img src="test.gif" galleryimg="no" />
```

Answer (score 5):

No it's not possible. The user can see the image in the browser and thus the browser (and the user) has a copy. You can try and restrict that with nasty (and ill-advised) right-click JS hacks and the like but ultimately if you send something to someone to see or read, what they do with it is beyond your control when you don't control the device they're using.

Comment: While true, this is not an answer to the question. Maybe an answer to the topic’s title, yes, but not to the actual question everything boils down to: “IN IE it shows Icons to Save Image, print , mail etc . I want to remove all of these . IS it possible ??”

Answer (score 3):

You can only do so much to prevent some users. To be near 100% foolproof, it's probably impossible. Even if you packaged the images in say, flash, java applet, it doesn't stop users from doing screencapture too.

There are few passive alternatives, e.g. using watermarks, putting up discalimers/warnings.

Here are some related SO posts:
[How to disable right-click save on one specific image only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678579/)
[Disable “Save Target As” option in the right click menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1385390/)
[Prevent Save As Functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300487/prevent-save-as-functionality)

Answer (score 2):

Prevent users from downloading images it's a waste of time because even if they cannot download the image, they always could do an **screenshot** :-(

Answer (score 1):

if you are using Apache server, you can disable accessing the image through absolute url
the images can be access only with relative url with this htaccess code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

in addition, disable the right click context using JavaScript, and add a watermark to protect the copy rights

this will reduce the chance of saving the images

Comment: But now not all my images load an i get forbidden apache. has access to all folders and files

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent the downloading of your images. Just by viewing them, the browser caches them.

Answer (score 0):

If the browser can get it, then the user can somehow get it.

You could investigate using an HTML5 canvas or even (gasp) pixelized tables to render client-side.

Comment: Screenshot! There's simply no way around it :)

Comment: Yep, absolutely correct, if the data no matter how disseminated is pushed one can always pull it back.

Answer (score -1):

```
.show_IMAGE
{
   background-position : 0 -100px;
   background-image : url('/images/flower.png');
   background-repeat : no-repeat;width:50px;height:50px;
}
```

and add this class to DIV

```
< div class="show_IMAGE"></ div>
```

you cannot copy the image alone. if you get image from CSS.

Comment: Not actually true. If you inspect the css properties, you get the path and can link out to it or even just save as when hovering over the image link.

Answer (score -1):

You may try following steps:

- Disable right click function on your website.
- Disable image dragging on the image you want `draggable="false"`

Now your website is image theft protected!

Comment: This is not correct, as the user can reverse both those steps, and anyway can still view, and save the image in a number of different ways